# HashMap implementation with the soft referenced values

Tags: java, hashmap, soft-references

I wanted to have a Map with key mapping to quite a big object.
Since the map is going to be used as a cache, I wanted to make the values/entries referenced via soft links (`java.lang.ref.SoftReference`) to clear it on pure memory. But in this case, I need to have my own implementation of `computeIfAbsent()` method.

I could implement it in the following way:

```
Map<Integer, SoftReference<T>> myMap = new HashMap<>();

public T get(Integer key) {
    SoftReference<T> value = myMap.get(key);
    if (value == null || value.get() == null) {
        value = new SoftReference(retrieveValue());
        myMap.put(key, value);
    }
    return value.get();
}
```

Just wanted to know, is there an out of the box solution for such a Map, like `java.util.WeakHashMap`?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is something like that in java out of the box, you need to implement it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Guava's [CacheBuilder](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) supports both SoftReference and WeakReference values, as well as other eviction policies based on size and time. You can use the Cache directly, or view it as a Map:

```
ConcurrentMap<Integer, V> map = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .softValues()
   .build()
   .asMap()
```

Comment: great alternative! Thanks!